# Append string at the end of url before extension

Tags: php, url, append

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/<?php echo $prod['item_image_url']; ?>" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><img src="images/<?php echo $prod['item_image_url']; ?>" alt="" /></a>
```

In this code `echo $prod['item_image_url'];` prints the images url that is stored in my table and prints like

```
href="images/new-thumb-01.jpg"
```

i am trying to convert this to

```
href="images/new-thumb-01-big.jpg"
```

without changing database entries.which means apped `"-big"` at the end of url but before `".jpg"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo) function:

```
$prod['item_image_url'] = "new-thumb-01.jpg";

$fileparts = pathinfo($prod['item_image_url']);

$bigFileName = $fileparts['filename'] . "-big." .$fileparts['extension'];
```

`$bigFileName` holds `new-thumb-01-big.jpg`

Comment: I like this solution because the explode solution below this can break if there are dots in the url aside from the one preceding the extension. And since pathinfo breaks the url into an array, I can add back in the directory part of the url using `$fileparts['dirname']` if I want. Super helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use explode() function

```
$url = "images/new-thumb-01.jpg";
$image = explode('.', $url);
$newUrl =  $image[0].'-big.'.$image[1]; 
echo $newUrl;
```

Hope this help's you..

Answer (score 1):

If file name is from database, and file maybe not exists on file system, you can use [substr_replace()](http://php.net/substr_replace) to insert specific string between file name:

```
<?php
$string = 'new-thumb-01.jpg';
$replacement = '-big';
echo substr_replace( $string , $replacement , strrpos($string, '.'), 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 You have to break filename and file extension and then add whatever file name 
 before extension.

 $fileOrg = $_FILES[0]['name'];
 $filenameOnly = array_pop(array_reverse(explode(".", $fileOrg )));
 $ext = end(explode('.', $fileOrg ));
 $filename = $filenameOnly . '-big' .'.' . $ext;
```